# C# Using Speech to recite strings from a listbox

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech

T I'm having lots of trouble trying to get my code's speech synthesis class to recite words from a ListBoxItem.toString(). 
the foreach loop in the btnStart_Clicked() method is where i believe the problem starts:

```
test = testLstSet.lstWordlist.Items.ToString();
speech.SpeakAsync(test);
```

the speech synth tells me:

> "system.windows.forms.listbox + object.collections"

could someone please help? sorry about all the code but i wanted to give you as much info as possible.

what am i doing wrong?

```
public partial class MyClass : Form
{
    private bool testStarted = false;
    private SpeechSynthesizer speech;
    private string evalWord = null;
    string test;
    bool testBit = false;

    TestList testLstSet;

    public SpellingBee(TestList tstLst)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        testLstSet = tstLst;

        speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        speech.SpeakAsync("Hello! Welcome to The test. Shall we begin?");
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (testStarted)
            return;
        else
        {
            testStarted = true;
            foreach(var item in wrdLstSet.lstWordlist.Items)
            {
                test = testLstSet.lstWordlist.Items.ToString();
                speech.SpeakAsync(test);
                while(!testBit)
                {
                }     
            }
        }           
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string evalWord = this.txtAnswer.Text;
        bool answer = string.Equals(evalWord, test, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (answer)
        {
            speech.SpeakAsync("That's right! Good Job!");
            testbit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            speech.SpeakAsync("That is incorrect.");
            testbit = true;
        }         
    }

}
```

}

Comment: testLstSet.lstWordlist.Items.ToString() - looks strange. Do you want to pronounce name of type for Items?

Comment: Maybe you want testLstSet.lstWordlist.Items[0].ToString();?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you want to achieve but I think you need part of your code to

```
foreach(var item in testLstSet.lstWordlist.Items)
        {
            speech.SpeakAsync(item.ToString());
        }
```

When you call `testLstSet.lstWordlist.Items.ToString();` - you are getting type of Items, that is `object.collections`. If you want to get element of this collection you should use indexer like this: `testLstSet.lstWordlist.Items[0].ToString();`

Comment: wow can't believe i missed that. thanks so much. sometimes all you need is another pair of eyes i guess.